# Set boolean state of tests after on click event handler callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a set of tests(dummy data) this array contains a few objects that each have a key named 'description' and 'run', the latter calls a function named makeDummyTest(). For each description a test should run, initially the test should have a state of -> did'nt run yet(null). When the button is clicked, the state changes to running. After the randomized delayed setTimeout, for each test in the tests array the state should change to the outcome of testPassed(= a randomly generated Boolean)resulting in a state and the display of either -> passed/failed.

When I click on the button, after a short delay, all tests start to fail-pass-fail-pass simultaneously ( for each test all change color according to their status).

How can I make sure that each tests outcome (true/false -> pass/fail) is connected to the corresponding test?

**Dummy Data**

```
import makeDummyTest from './makeDummyTest.js';

const tests = [
    { description: "uploads go in both directions",          run: makeDummyTest() },
    { description: "PDFs are adequately waterproof",         run: makeDummyTest() },
    { description: "videos are heated to 12,000,000 Kelvin", run: makeDummyTest() },
    { description: "subpixels can go rock climbing",         run: makeDummyTest() },
    { description: "images are squarer than traffic cones",  run: makeDummyTest() },
    { description: "metaproperties don't go too meta",       run: makeDummyTest() },
  ];


export default tests;
```

**makeDummyTest Function**

```
const makeDummyTest = () => {
    const delay = 7000 + Math.random() * 7000;
    const testPassed = Math.random() > 0.5;

    return callback => {
      window.setTimeout(() => callback(testPassed), delay);
    };
  };


  export default makeDummyTest;
```

**The state**

```
    this.state = {
      noClick: true,
      testStatus: 'not started',
      tests: tests
    };
```

**App constructor method with component level state**

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicked: false,
      testStatus: {},
      tests: tests
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

  }
```

**Click handler**

```
  handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { tests } = this.state;
    this.setState({testStatus: 'running', clicked: true})
    tests.map(test => {
        test.run((x) =>   x === true ? this.setState({testStatus: 'passed'}) : this.setState({testStatus: 'failed'}))
    }) 
  }
```

**The render method**

```
    render() {

    const { clicked, testStatus } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="RootContainer">
        <h1>Test Runner</h1>

        <div className="testsList">
          {(this.state.tests).map(test => {

            return (
              <div key={test.description}>
                <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
                  <p>{test.description}</p>
                  {!clicked && <span style={{background:'grey'}}>Test did not run yet</span>}
                  {clicked && testStatus === 'running' && <span style={{background:'limegreen'}}>Test is running</span>}
                  {testStatus === 'passed' && <span style={{background:'green'}}>Test passed</span>}
                  {testStatus === 'failed' && <span style={{background:'darkred'}}>Test failed</span>}
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <button className="testRunner" onClick={this.handleClick}>Run these tests</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what's going on here. Right now you're setting `run` to the results of calling `makeDummyTest` which will be a function. In `handleClick` you iterate over the tests and set `testPassed` to `run.testPassed`, which won't exist, because `run` is a function. Even if it *did* work you'd be setting a single value to the result of running all of the tests, meaning it'll oscillate indeterminately as each test passes or fails.

Comment: What I would like to accomplish is when I click the button, for each test in the array -> run the function and return the value of testPassed and set state to that value.

I know my approach is missing a set of steps. Could you maybe give some pointers on how to approach it?
How  can I make it clearer what I'm trying to do?

Comment: The tests will finish at an arbitrary point in the future, and since the timeout values are random, they won't finish in a determinate order. Are you saying you want to wait until one has finished before starting the other? Also why would you want to keep track of a single test's pass/fail status in the overall state? Wouldn't it make more sense to keep track of each test's status?

Comment: Yes that totally makes sense, I would like all tests to start running at the same time when the button is clicked and keep track of the state of each individual test is in. 
'Asynchronously' (after setTimeout resolves) resulting in different outcomes per test.

Comment: I am  really drawing a blank atm on returning the value of testPassed 
I don't get why it returns the callback 6 times and doesn't invoke the callback 
giving me access to the value of testPassed 

`const makeDummyTest = () => {
    const delay = 7000 + Math.random() * 7000;
    const testPassed = Math.random() > 0.5;
  
    return callback => {
      window.setTimeout(() => callback(testPassed), delay);
    };
  };`

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Because you never call it. You're returning a function you never call. Even if you did you'll still run into the same problem with them ending at arbitrary times and you only store a single `testPassed` value. You might want to take a step back and figure out what you're *actually* trying to do, and maybe brush up on general async programming basics.

Comment: use this.setState(prevState=>{})